# Possible to add auto incrementing variable to row results of GROUP BY in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Basically, I'm using this query to group a bunch of users based on the sum of numbers associated with them.  I need to some how assign an index to each result.  I am blanking on how to do this.  I'm thinking I need to alias something with AS but not sure quite how.  Any ideas?

This is the current query where I switch out the page and per dynamically:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, user_id, SUM(earnings) as sum FROM ci_league_result
 GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY sum desc LIMIT ".$page.', '.$per;
```

I'm lookin for it to work something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, user_id, SUM(earnings) as sum, *NEW-RESULTS-OVERALL-INDEX* AS newindex FROM ci_league_result
GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY sum desc LIMIT ".$page.', '.$per;
```

notice the AS newindex in the second query.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Temporary tables might be a solution for your problem. Structurally add a auto_incremented column to the temp table definition. Views might also be a solution, allowing you to avoid running a quite consuming query alot of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, count, sum, @row := @row + 1 AS newindex FROM
(SELECT
   COUNT(*) as count,
   user_id,
   SUM(earnings) as sum
FROM ci_league_result 
GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY sum desc LIMIT ".$page.', '.$per) r
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) rr;
```

**EDITED**

Comment: hmmm this is returning an inaccurate result for me currently

Comment: you'll need to give that derived table (after the CROSS JOIN) an alias.

Comment: Ya this worked perfectly! What does the 'r' before the cross join do?  edit oh wait its an alias.  Didn't recognize it since I thought AS was required.

Comment: @John B:  AS keyword is optional. We typically include the AS keyword on column aliases, and omit the AS keyword on table aliases. (Note that some other DBMSs don't accept the AS keyword on table aliases).

Comment: @John B: I assume you have already did this somewhere in your code, but I have no idea how the rest of your code looks like. But make sure the `$per` and `$page` are escaped to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this with `SQL` [variables](http://domoconnor.com/2009/04/22/getting-the-current-row-number-from-mysql/)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as count,
  user_id,
  SUM(earnings) as sum,
  @rownum := @rownum+1 AS newindex
FROM ci_league_result,
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY sum DESC
LIMIT ".$page.', '.$per;
```

Comment: looks like you're missing a JOIN keyword before the inline view.

Comment: @spencer7593 I don' think so. I tried it on a similar table, are you sure?

Comment: I can't fathom how that statement won't throw a a syntax error, absent a comma or a JOIN keyword after `ci_league_result` and before the inline view.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks missed the comma. but i dont see why a join would be needed after `ci_league_result`. Can you explain why you need a `JOIN`.

Comment: The "comma" between the tablename and the inline view (in your statement) is a JOIN; that comma IS a join operator. The comma can be replaced with the keyword JOIN.  (I would replace the comma with `CROSS JOIN`. The `CROSS` keyword has no influence on the statement, it just serves to document (to a later reader) that our intent was to omit an ON clause, as in the answer from Hamlet.)